# Unable to reach a function inside SignalR connection function

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am trying to access a function inside a SignalR connection function. To better illustrate this is the code for the whole script.

```
$(function() {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.informOfStatusRequest = function(personToNotify, message) {
        var sysUserId = @Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sys_user_id"].Value);
        if (sysUserId === personToNotify) {
            $.notify({
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                message: message
            }, {
                animate: {
                    enter: 'animated fadeInRight',
                    exit: 'animated fadeOutRight'
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

        function disapproveTicket(ticketId, createdById) {
            bootbox.confirm({
                title: 'CONFIRM',
                message: 'Disapprove ticket ID ' +ticketId +'?',
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'YES',
                        className: 'btn-success'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'NO',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                },
                callback: function(response) {
                    if (response === true) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/Member/DisapprovePendingTicket',
                            data: {ticketId: ticketId} ,
                            success: function(result) {
                                if (result === true) {
                                    $.notify({
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                                        message: "Ticket has been disaproved"
                                    }, {
                                        animate: {
                                            enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                                            exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        type: 'success'
                                    });
                                    $("#div_get_pending_ticket").load('/Member/GetPendingTicket');
                                    getPendingRequestCount();
                                    chat.server.informUserOnRequestStatus(createdById,"Ticket has been disaproved");
                                } else {
                                    $.notify({
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
                                        message: "Failed in disapproving the ticket."
                                    }, {
                                        animate: {
                                            enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                                            exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        type: 'success'
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and this is how I try to access the "disapproveTicket" function:

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="">Check</a> |
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="disapproveTicket(@item.TicketId, @item.CreatedById)">Disapprove</a>
</td>
```

On my console it says that "disapproveTicket is undefined". The disapproveTicket is inside a $(function()) and is inside $.connection.hub.start().done(). I've seen other answers on how to access nested functions but the structure is different from what I have. Can you please show me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your function disapproveTicket() is can be use when  $.connection.hub.start().done(). so that the onclick attribute in html element can't call it. i think you must use

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function(){
   $("#your_element").click(function(){
      disapproveTicket()
   })
})
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: I can see the javascript in the HTML. Somehow it just can't be reached. I am guessing maybe because it is inside another function. That's where I need help.

Comment: i edit my answer, sorry because at the first i didn't see you use $(function(){})

Comment: If I use it like that, how can I pass my parameters? I am passing '@item.TicketId and @item.CreatedById' from my partial view.

Comment: disapproveTicket(@item.TicketId, @item.CreatedById)

Comment: '@item.TicketId, @item.CreatedById' are values from my table rows. If I can't get it from $("#your_element").click(function(){ then I can't pass it to the disapproveTicket()

Comment: it have many way to do it, i think you must resolve it by your self. it didn't hard like you worry. =).